# Reverse resolution of URLs in Django with multiple url parameters

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

In my blog app I need to show articles based on the url:

```
app_name = 'blog_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:article_id>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

The structure of the project is:
*myblog* points to *portal* (for login); after login *portal* points to *blog_app* (which contains the articles list).
So the steps to show articles are:

**mysite_index --> portal_login --> blog_app_index**

In *portal* app, after login, using a button I want to go to the **index view of blog_app**. So I need to specify all url parameters, and I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="
  {% url 'blog_app:index' 
       user_id = user.id 
       year = {% now "Y" %} 
       month = {% now "m" %} 
  %}
">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go</button>
</a>
{% endif %}
```

I don't know why the URL becomes: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/%7B%25%20url%20'blog_app:index'%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20user_id%20%3D%20user.id%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20year%20%3D%202022%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20month%20%3D%2008%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%25%7D`

**What I'm doing wrong? How I should do this type of reversing?**

Comment: I believe you need to have it surrounded in curly braces only `{{ … }}` instead of `{% … %}`. The url is encoded instead of what you expect, and I believe the above will help.

Comment: @Jarvis Can you be more specific about what I should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `{% ... %}` inside another `{% ... %}`. Another thing is you are placing a lot of "enters" and whitespaces into `href` and curly brackets. Do it in one line and leave no whitespace unless it's necessary (even around `=`), which is encoded with `%20`.

You can get current year and current month with adding `timezone.now()` as context, in example:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...
context = {..., "today": timezone.now()}
```

Then in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_app:index' user_id=user.id year=today.year month=today.month %}">
```